# Java Static and Thread safety

Tags: java

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
public static String data = "" ;
public Thread1(String tname){
    super(tname);
}
public void run(){
    synchronized (Thread1.data){
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if(this.getName().equals("T1")){
                Thread1.data = "Thread1";
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){}
                System.out.println(getName()+":"+Thread1.data );
            }else if (this.getName().equals("T2")){
                Thread1.data  = "Thread2";
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){}
                System.out.println(getName()+":"+Thread1.data );
            }
        }
    }
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread a1 = new Thread1("T1");
    Thread a2 = new Thread1("T2");
    a1.start();
    a2.start();
}
}
```

outputs:
T2:Thread2

T1:Thread2

T2:Thread1

T1:Thread2

T2:Thread1

T1:Thread2

T2:Thread1

T1:Thread2

T2:Thread1

T1:Thread1

What's the situation? Why can't data be used as synchornized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You reassign the value of `data`.

```
Thread1.data = "Thread1";
// ...
Thread1.data = "Thread2";
```

This means that `Thread1` obtains a lock on the `""` object, and then `Thread2` obtains a lock on the `"Thread1"` object, which is a completely different entity. If you want the two threads to synchronize on the same object, you need to make sure `Thread1.data` doesn't change what it's pointing to. The easiest way to do this would be to have a separate lock object.

```
public static final Object lock = new Object();

// Then, inside the function...
synchronized (Thread1.lock) {
   // ...
}
```

Since `Thread1.lock` is never reassigned, it will always refer to the same object and, by extension, the same lock. Making it `final` will ensure that any accidental attempts to reassign it will fail at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void run() {
        synchronized (Thread1.class) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

because the object lock data is always changed when you use following sentense:
Thread1.data = "Thread1";
so you can't endure two threads synchronized.